# PHP: If many objects use instance of the same object - what is an efficient way to pass it?

Tags: php, object, pass-by-reference

For example, my app is using instance of a User object, and different other objects have to access some attributes and methods. And these objects instantiate other objects, which in turn also have to access User. What's the best way to manage this? Pass User object as reference when I instantiate these new objects?

Here's example of how this is done now:

```
class App {
  private $user;
  private $controller;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->user = new User();
    $this->controller = new Controller();
    $this->controller->setUser(& $this->user);
  }  
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

**EDIT:** Is there a way to make User instance a global var?

Comment: PHP5 passes objects by reference by default, so don't need to do it explicitly

Comment: Look at the Singleton-Pattern. Maybe it fits better here.

Comment: @Paul, that's not entirely true. It passes a handle by value. But your advice is still correct ... drop the `&` in the function call.

Comment: See my edit: is it better to make User instance a global var?

Comment: @SODA, does User always represent the same data during the duration of a script? (e.g., The user making the request.)

Comment: Singleton pattern looks interesting

Comment: @konforce - No, it's possible for one user to perform actions on other user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make User instance a global var?

It sounds like a singleton would be helpful:

```
class User
{
  private static $instance;

  private function __construct() { } 

  public function instance()
  {
    return self::$instance ? self::$instance : (self::$instance = new self());
  }
}

$user = User::instance();
```

Basically anything that needs the user, can just call `User::instance()` instead of `new User()`. They will all be operating on the same instance of the object, so this is only applicable of the User object represents the same data throughout the duration of the script.

**Update**

With your comment "No, it's possible for one user to perform actions on other user," then this pattern is not applicable for every usage.

Sounds like you just need to pass the `$user` object along to anybody that needs it. (Of course, you could still use a singleton to represent the authenticated user.)

Comment: What if I need to get an instance for another user? In case visitor (who is instantiated as User) needs to perform action that involved data of another user?

Comment: You could pass a parameter to `instance()` and cache the data.

Comment: Well I guess question is if technically I can use same class to use both as singleton AND to instantiate via __construct for other users?

Comment: Actually, never mind, wouldn't hurt to make another class for users, it would be a smaller one as it would not deal with sessions etc, only with user data

Comment: Correct, you should use different classes for the two. The AuthenticatedUser could possibly subclass the User class, or even just contain an instance of the User class within itself using a has-a relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make my suggestion in the comments to an answer

You can implement the singleton pattern

```
class User {
    protected static $instance = null;
    protected function __construct () { /* disable external instanciation */ }
    private function __clone () { /* disable clone */ }
    public static function getInstance () {
        if (is_null(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Here is something to read :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern